# Hibernate throwing an error message. But saving the data into database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We are using Hibernate and MySQL in our project. We are using saveOrUpdate() method for updating data.
Our problem When We update the existing data first we are checking some conditions. If those conditions are passed we are throwing error like below snippet code.
Else we are saving the data. We put debug and checked at the saveOrUpdate() method. It is not going to saveOrUpdate(). But some how data is saving into database.

**This is DAO layer**

```
 public List<Student> getOverlappingStudentDetails(String studentId, String classNumber){
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class, "student");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("student.id", studentId));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("student.classNumnber", classNumber));
    return criteria.list();
}

public Student save(Student student) {
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(student);
session.flush();
return student;
}
```

**This is service implementation**

```
  private void checkForOverlappingStudentDetails(Student student) {
        List<Student> overlappingStudents = studentDAO.getOverlappingStudentDetails(student.getStudentId(),student.getClassName());
        if (overlappingStudents.size() >0 ) {
            throw new ValidationException(student.getName() + " is already present." ;
    }
}
```

It is throwing error. But, data is overriding into database. Is there any solution to stop the data to for updating. We tried session.clear() and we are using session.flush() method after saving the method.

Comment: "When We update the existing data first we are checking some conditions. If those conditions are passed we are throwing error like below snippet code. Else we are saving the data." -> There is no such conditional logic in your snippets.

Comment: last service layer says that right?. If you have some existing students. we are checking the size of the list. If that list is greater than 0 we are throwing error.

     private void checkForOverlappingStudentDetails(Student student) {
        List<Student> overlappingStudents = studentDAO.getOverlappingStudentDetails(student.getStudentId(),student.getClassName());
        if (overlappingStudents.size() >0 ) {
            throw new ValidationException(student.getName() + " is already present." ;
    }
}

Comment: @fg78nc is there any thing in hbm file where we need to add code for saveOrUpdate()?